# Need a help about tensorflow related warning

Tags: 16.04, cpu

I have installed Tensorflow on Ubuntu 16.04 and tested it with simple code. The result is executed, but there are some things (probably, warnings) that scare me a bit. They are given below:

`W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.`

I posted this question because I think every case is different from another, especially, those where the warnings say about `SSE3` , `SSE4.1`, `SSE4.2`, `AVX`, `FMA`. 
If you have any suggestions to handle this, please give me a hand